# UIView frame changes from viewWillAppear: to viewDidAppear:

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad

I'm initializing a `UIView` with the frame: `CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768)`. Everything seems right, until its superview enters the `viewDidAppear:` method. The frame changes to `768, 1024`. The problem only occurs when the `Status bar is initially hidden` property is set to `YES`. The frame does not change if the status bar is shown.

I have checked the `UIInterfaceOrientation` in `viewWillAppear:` and `viewDidAppear:` and it does not change between the two methods.

Why does the frame's height and width swap when the status bar is hidden?

Comment: Where you are setting status bar hidden to NO?

Comment: You can try one thing, in app delegate set wantsFullScreenLayout property of viewController as YES and check, not sure though whether it will work for you or not, seems like a strange issue, also can you tell me where and how you are handling orientation of application, might be that is the cause of this issue.

Comment: Thanks man! The wantsFullScreenLayout property fixed the problem. The documentation describes, that this property should be set to YES when hiding the statusbar. But it is still quite weird, that the UIView swaps height and width.

Comment: It is actually not weird when it is mentioned in documentation do like this. :) Now i am posting this as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `app delegate` set `wantsFullScreenLayout` property of `viewController` to YES.

Comment: wantsFullScreenLayout is deprecated since iOS7 - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19190876/need-wantsfullscreenlayout-behavior-with-non-translucent-bars-on-ios-7