# Need wantsFullScreenLayout behavior with NON-translucent bars on iOS 7

Tags: ios, ios7, uinavigationbar, uitoolbar, xcode5

I want to be able to have my view cover the whole screen (go behind the navigation and tool bars) with the translucent property of the navigationBar and toolbar set to **NO** (I want non-transparent bars).

This was easy to accomplish prior to iOS 7 by setting `wantsFullScreenLayout` to YES. However, in iOS 7, I can't find any way of doing this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

`wantsFullScreenLayout` is deprecated at iOS 7. Try setting your view controller's `edgesForExtendedLayout` property to `UIRectEdgeAll`

The iOS 7 Transition Guide mentions a few of the new view controller differences on page 17. However, the documentation states that if you're using opaque bars (as in your case) you should also set:

```
extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = YES;
```

**EDIT**

.. because by default it is `NO`. This conflicts with the iOS 7 Transition Guide which states the default value is `YES`. Be warned.

Comment: By default, `edgesForExtendedLayout` is set to `UIRectEdgeAll`.

Comment: Yes, but it's possible the OP might have adjusted it somewhere along the way.

Comment: Sure. The craze these days around SO is to solve all problems by setting to `UIRectEdgeNone` instead of understanding the problems and solving them properly. The most annoying answers I see are "just revert to old way by `UIRectEdgeNone`. Ugh!

Comment: BTW, a little off topic, but it seems even Apple solved some of their classes' problems by setting to `UIRectEdgeNone`. :-)

Comment: I got it to work! The solution was to set `extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars` to **YES** on the `UIViewController`. The `edgesForExtendedLayout` needs to be on `UIRectEdgeAll`, but that is set by default, so no need to make a change to that. Anyway, if you revise your answer, I will accept it. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Its frustrating, I know. You might try looking at your XIB (if you're using one) as well as examining the arrangement of your view hierarchy to ensure that you're setting these properties in the correct place.

Comment: What's weird about your solution is: The Transition Guide states "If you're design uses opaque bars, refine `edgesForExtendedLayout` by also setting the `extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars` to NO." You're saying that the opposite is happening. Could be a bug. Not sure.

Comment: I know, they made an error. One minor correction to the last sentence in your answer: the default value of `extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars` is NO. You can verify this by checking in code, or also reading the doc that comes up in Xcode when you select the property.

Comment: You're right. I just double checked the docs! It's conflicting with the transition guide.

Answer (score -1):

```
picker.edgesForExtendedLayout = YES;
```

Comment: Please extend your answer with description.

Comment: `edgesForExtendedLayout` is a variable of UIRectEdge type, it cannot be `YES`.